# INNER JOIN in a long query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just landed at this new job and there´s a report where I´m asked to show an information stored in a another table, so I need to enhance the existing query that was developed by someone that left the company.

The query is fairly long and I´m not getting where I should insert the INNER JOIN clause that will retrieve the information I need.

This is the original code:

```
    SELECT ToolLists.Ident,
       ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript,
       ToolLists.MaterialNr,
       ToolLists.Order,
       ToolLists.Who,
       ToolLists.NCP,
       ToolLists.Rem AS TLRem,
       ToolLists.MDate,
       ToolLists.TDate,
       ToolLists.GDate,
       ToolList.T,
       Machines.Name AS MachineName,
       Machines.TRelation,
       ToolList.D,
       ToolList.H,
       ToolList.Pos AS ToolListPos,
       ToolList.Rem AS ToolListRem,
       ToolList.How AS ToolListHow,
       Tools.Nr,
       Tools.Z1,
       Tools.Drawing,
       Tools.X1,
       Tools.Sort,
       Tools.Design,
       Tools.Descript,
       Tools.Rem AS ToolRem,
       ToolParts.Pos AS ToolPartPos,
       ToolParts.Nbr,
       ToolParts.How,
       Parts.UNr,
       Parts.MID,
       Parts.Descript,
       Parts.Sort,
       Parts.Design,
       Parts.URem,
       Parts.DMC,
       Parts.CLength,
       Parts.CMainArc,
       Parts.CRadius,
       Parts.UActiv,
       MatClasses.DMC,
       MatClasses.Description,
       MatClasses.Quality,
       NoteToolLists.NoteText
FROM Parts
INNER JOIN ( (Machines
              RIGHT JOIN ( (MatClasses
                            RIGHT JOIN (NoteToollists
                                        RIGHT JOIN (Materials
                                                    RIGHT JOIN ([SELECT ID, Param1 FROM WTDIDList WHERE WTGUID = '4a9b5a05-fa43-48d1-af2f-342ea407f4e2']. AS IDList
                                                                INNER JOIN ToolLists ON IDList.ID = ToolLists.Nr) ON Materials.Nr = ToolLists.MaterialNr) ON NoteToolLists.Nr = ToolLists.Nr) ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr)
                          INNER JOIN (Tools
                                      INNER JOIN ToolList ON Tools.Nr = ToolList.ToolNr) ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr)
            INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr) ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID
ORDER BY ToolLists.Nr,
         ToolList.Pos,
         ToolList.T;
```

There´s a table called `SiteParts` containing a column named `Place` - I need to retrieve the value in this column where the value of the column `PartId` is equal to the column `ID`in the table `Parts`

So I tried to add this to the code above:

`INNER JOIN (SELECT Place FROM SiteParts) ON SiteParts.PartId = Parts.ID`

So this was my attempt:

```
 SELECT ToolLists.Ident,
           ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript,
           ToolLists.MaterialNr,
           ToolLists.Order,
           ToolLists.Who,
           ToolLists.NCP,
           ToolLists.Rem AS TLRem,
           ToolLists.MDate,
           ToolLists.TDate,
           ToolLists.GDate,
           ToolList.T,
           Machines.Name AS MachineName,
           Machines.TRelation,
           ToolList.D,
           ToolList.H,
           ToolList.Pos AS ToolListPos,
           ToolList.Rem AS ToolListRem,
           ToolList.How AS ToolListHow,
           Tools.Nr,
           Tools.Z1,
           Tools.Drawing,
           Tools.X1,
           Tools.Sort,
           Tools.Design,
           Tools.Descript,
           Tools.Rem AS ToolRem,
           ToolParts.Pos AS ToolPartPos,
           ToolParts.Nbr,
           ToolParts.How,
           Parts.UNr,
           Parts.MID,
           Parts.Descript,
           Parts.Sort,
           Parts.Design,
           Parts.URem,
           Parts.DMC,
           Parts.CLength,
           Parts.CMainArc,
           Parts.CRadius,
           Parts.UActiv,
           MatClasses.DMC,
           MatClasses.Description,
           MatClasses.Quality,
           NoteToolLists.NoteText,
           SiteParts.Place
    FROM Parts
    INNER JOIN ( (Machines
                  RIGHT JOIN ( (MatClasses
                                RIGHT JOIN (NoteToollists
                                            RIGHT JOIN (Materials
                                                        RIGHT JOIN ([SELECT ID, Param1 FROM WTDIDList WHERE WTGUID = '4a9b5a05-fa43-48d1-af2f-342ea407f4e2']. AS IDList
                                                                    INNER JOIN ToolLists ON IDList.ID = ToolLists.Nr)
                                                        INNER JOIN
                                                          (SELECT Place
                                                           FROM SiteParts)) ON Materials.Nr = ToolLists.MaterialNr) ON NoteToolLists.Nr = ToolLists.Nr) ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr)
                  INNER JOIN (Tools
                              INNER JOIN ToolList ON Tools.Nr = ToolList.ToolNr) ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr)
    INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr) ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID ON PartId = Parts.Id
    ORDER BY ToolLists.Nr,
             ToolList.Pos,
             ToolList.T;
```

But the server is rejecting my query, with the following message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I have revisited this a bunch of times but i´m not being able to handle this long query correctly. Can someone point me what I´m doing wrong?

It´s obvious I´m not good in SQL as the previous guy, but I need to catch up and try to make things to work with the current code rather re-write it just because I don´t get it how he made it.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your query so that it is readable.

Comment: you said you tried to add `INNER JOIN (SELECT Place FROM SiteParts) ON PartId = Parts.ID` to the query, but I see in the final query no `ON` clause near `INNER JOIN (SELECT Place FROM SiteParts) )`

Comment: Why all these ( ) in your joins ? are you sure this is sql server it looks like access with all these ( ) you are using

Comment: @dubes No `ON` clause is probably logically wrong, but the query would still execute with a cross join.  Maybe something else is going on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Excellent point, however the error message shows `Incorrect Syntax on Line 9 near )` which would be the missing ON clause, perhaps his DB vendor is unforgiving on missing ON clause?

Comment: I agree the query seems overly complex, but it is the code that is working or a couple of years. I´m trying to get it to work with the extra column I´m trying to retrieve.

Comment: @DanielSantos if the `INNER JOIN (SELECT Place ...`  is the only change, can you please try with adding the `ON` clause... if you have tried that already let us know

Comment: what is going on where you've got RIGHT JOIN ([SELECT ID, Param1 FROM WTDIDList WHERE WTGUID = '4a9b5a05-fa43-48d1-af2f-342ea407f4e2']. AS IDList   the entire SQL has square brackets around it, making it into a literal  -  I get your syntax error on the WORKING version - unless I change order to 'ToolLists.[Order]' - then the part I was asking about with [....SQL...] throws a syntax error out

Answer (score 1):

Even though the query is quite complex and could use some rewriting, the answer should be quite simple.

Add this to the `SELECT`-part:

```
SiteParts.Place
```

... as you did already in your attempt (with a comma between this entry and the previous/next entries).

Then add this in a new line just above the `ORDER BY`-line:

```
INNER JOIN SiteParts ON SiteParts.PartId = Parts.ID
```

That should do it.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the code in a comment? It seems too long for stackoverflow...

Comment: After @Peter B suggestion, I´m getting the following error from `Stimulsoft`   `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID
INNER JOIN SiteParts ON SiteParts.PartId = Parts.ID'.`

Comment: In that case, cut all the `ON ...` conditions that are now immediately before the newly added part, and paste them just behind the newly added part -> so after my `ON ...`. If needed, try various arrangements of the individual `ON ... ` parts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the WORKING SQL posted has syntax errors - the whole of the SQL beginning 'SELECT ID, Param1 FROM WTDIDList' is enclosed in [...] making it into a table name - please check the original works and is the correct version!    After the SQL becomes a table name due to the [  ] the ON pattern is not followed and there is a spurious dot, so you will get confusing syntax errors unless it is sorted - maybe the brackets and dot should not be there

Comment: have you got an original copy/copies in source control?  Could he have dabbled and not rolled out the latest version - it looks odd to me - if it is some new SQL invention - I'm sorry - you never know what they will come up with next!

Comment: The original code works... By the way this query is set up inside a  Stimulsoft report... It works from there...

Answer (score 0):

This code works - Had to rewrite it a bit but it works now:

```
    SELECT ToolLists.Ident,
       ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript,
       ToolLists.MaterialNr,
       ToolLists.Order,
       ToolLists.Who,
       ToolLists.NCP,
       ToolLists.Rem AS TLRem,
       ToolLists.MDate,
       ToolLists.TDate,
       ToolLists.GDate,
       ToolList.T,
       Machines.Name AS MachineName,
       Machines.TRelation,
       ToolList.D,
       ToolList.H,
       ToolList.Pos AS ToolListPos,
       ToolList.Rem AS ToolListRem,
       ToolList.How AS ToolListHow,
       Tools.Nr,
       Tools.Z1,
       Tools.Drawing,
       Tools.X1,
       Tools.Sort,
       Tools.Design,
       Tools.Descript,
       Tools.Rem AS ToolRem,
       ToolParts.Pos AS ToolPartPos,
       ToolParts.Nbr,
       ToolParts.How,
       Parts.UNr,
       Parts.MID,
       Parts.Descript,
       Parts.Sort,
       Parts.Design,
       Parts.URem,
       Parts.DMC,
       Parts.CLength,
       Parts.CMainArc,
       Parts.CRadius,
       Parts.UActiv,
       MatClasses.DMC,
       MatClasses.Description,
       MatClasses.Quality
FROM (Parts
      RIGHT JOIN ((Machines
                   RIGHT JOIN ((MatClasses
                                RIGHT JOIN (Materials
                                            RIGHT JOIN (
                                                          (SELECT ID,
                                                                  Param1
                                                           FROM WTDIDList
                                                           WHERE WTGUID = '0e2c2ffe-6c09-4866-a114-5c0e2fe6260c' ) AS IDList
                                                        INNER JOIN ToolLists ON IDList.ID = ToolLists.Nr) ON Materials.Nr = ToolLists.MaterialNr) ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr)
                               INNER JOIN (Tools
                                           INNER JOIN ToolList ON Tools.Nr = ToolList.ToolNr) ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr)
                  INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr) ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT PartId,
          Place
   FROM SiteParts
   WHERE SiteNr = 1) AS SP ON SP.PartId = Parts.Id
ORDER BY ToolLists.Nr,
         ToolList.Pos,
         ToolList.T;
```

The solution as a LEFT JOIN in the end of the query.

Thank you each and everyone for the helpful inputs!